# Why am I getting this "NoSuchMethodError" in my code?

Tags: java, constructor

Everytime I run my code, I get this error below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void Car.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, double, double, double)'
    at DimaweaJeshuaAssignment11.setUpCars(DimaweaJeshuaAssignment11.java:48)
    at DimaweaJeshuaAssignment11.main(DimaweaJeshuaAssignment11.java:11)
```

I looked to see if my constructor in my Car class was correct, and it was, but I'm stuck and can't figure out what the problem is. This is my code below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class DimaweaJeshuaAssignment11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // create an array of 5 Car objects
        Car[] cars = new Car[5];
        // set up the cars
        setUpCars(cars);
        // output the car details to file
        writeCarDetailsToFile(cars);
        // display the cars at the start of simulation
        System.out.println("Cars at start of simulation");
        printCars(cars);
        
        int milesTraveled = 0;
        boolean allCarsHaveGas = true;
        
        // loop that continues until at least one of the cars has run out of gas
        while(allCarsHaveGas) {
            milesTraveled++; // increment the miles traveled
            // loop to decrement the gallons after traveling 1 mile
            for(int i=0;i<cars.length;i++) {
                cars[i].updateFuel(1);
                if(cars[i].getFuelGauge().getGallons() == 0) { // check if any of cars have run out of gas, update allCarsHaveGas to false
                allCarsHaveGas = false;
                }
            }
        }
        
        // display the car details at the end of simulation
        System.out.println("Cars at end of simulation");
        printCars(cars);
        // loop to display the first car that ran out of gas
        for(int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
            if(cars[i].getFuelGauge().getGallons() == 0) {
                System.out.println("\n"+cars[i].getOwner()+"'s car ran out of has after "+ milesTraveled +" miles");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // method to set up the cars for the simulation based on the given information
    public static void setUpCars(Car[] cars) {
        
        cars[0] = new Car("Shrek", "Toyota Tundra", 15, 6, 20000);
        cars[1] = new Car("Fiona", "Audi Q7", 21, 10, 8270);
        cars[2] = new Car("Donkey", "Jeep CJ5", 14, 5, 11800);
        cars[3] = new Car("Farquaad", "Smart Car", 42, 4, 710);
        cars[4] = new Car("Dragon", "Chevy Suburban", 12, 30, 10800);
    }
    
    // method to display the details of the car in the array
    public static void printCars(Car[] cars) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.printf("%-20s%-20s%20s%20s\n","Owner","Brand","MPG","Current Gallons", "Mileage");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        for(int i=0;i<cars.length;i++)
        System.out.printf("%-20s%-20s%20.2f%20.2f\n",cars[i].getOwner(),cars[i].getBrand(),cars[i].getFuelEconomy(),cars[i].getFuelGauge().getGallons(), cars[i].getMileage());
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    // method to display the details of cars in the array to file
    public static void writeCarDetailsToFile(Car[] cars) throws IOException {
        // setup the file reference variable to refer to the text file
        File filename = new File("Assignment11.txt");
        
        // Create the file that the cars will be written to
        PrintWriter resultsFile = new PrintWriter(filename);
        
        // Write the details for each car to the file
        for(int i=0;i<cars.length;i++) {
            resultsFile.println(cars[i].getOwner());
            resultsFile.println(cars[i].getBrand());
            resultsFile.println(cars[i].getFuelEconomy());
            resultsFile.println(cars[i].getFuelGauge().getGallons());
        }
        
        resultsFile.close();
    }
} 
    

class Car {

    // attributes
    private String owner;
    private String brand;
    private double milesPerGallon;
    private FuelGauge fuelGauge;
    private double mileage;
    
    // constructor to initialize fields to specified values
    public Car(String owner, String brand, double milesPerGallon, double gallons, double mileage) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.milesPerGallon = milesPerGallon;
        fuelGauge = new FuelGauge();
        fuelGauge.setGallons(gallons);
        this.mileage = mileage;
    }
    
    // getters
    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
    
    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }
    
    public double getFuelEconomy() {
        return milesPerGallon;
    }
    
    public FuelGauge getFuelGauge() {
        return fuelGauge;
    }
    
    public double getMileage() {
        return mileage;
    }
    
    // update the fuel of the car based on the miles traveled
    public void updateFuel(double milesTraveled) {
        
        double gallonsUsed = milesTraveled/milesPerGallon; // compute the gallons used for traveling milesTraveled
        fuelGauge.decrementGallons(gallonsUsed); // decrement the gallons used
    }
    
} 


class FuelGauge {

    // attribute
    private double gallons;
    
    // default constructor that initialize gallons to 0
    public FuelGauge() {
        
    }
    
    
    // setter
    public void setGallons(double gallons) {
        
        this.gallons = gallons;
    }
        
    // getter
    public double getGallons() {
        return gallons;
    }
    
    // method to decrement the gallons by gallons used
    public void decrementGallons(double gallonsUsed) {
        if(gallonsUsed <= gallons) { // gallonsUsed <= gallons, decrement gallonsUsed from gallons
            gallons -= gallonsUsed;
        } else // gallonsUsed > gallons, set gallons to 0
            gallons = 0;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Recompile your code and try again.

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` almost always means that something that existed at compile time is missing at runtime. Have you re-compiled *everything*? Do you by chance have multiple versions of `Car.class` lying around on your classpath? I'd suggest `mvn clean compile` or whatever the equivalent is where you build.

Comment: BTW, good job showing your code and the error, but it would be good to remember the "minimal" part of "minimal reproducible example". Also, SO doesn't show line numbers, so it's a good practice to add comments indicating the lines to which the stack trace refers.

Comment: I can run this in an online IDE and it works fine, so as others have said, something's gone wrong in your compilation pipeline.